# JavaScript loop doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner and I am trying to override that the `:hover` pseudo-class in CSS doesn't let me trigger an event if the element that I am hovering over is below some other element.

If I hover over the div, the css transition kicks in, however, if I go over the text that is visually above the div, nothing happens.

I have four such elements, so I was trying to use getElementsByClassName to create the array to be iterated in JavaScript, but the console gives me always the same error of

```
    index.html:77 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of 
    undefined
    at stretchback (index.html:77)
    at HTMLParagraphElement.onmouseout (index.html:24)
    stretchback @ index.html:77
    onmouseout @ index.html:24

<script>
    var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('skill-box');
    function stretch() {
    for (var i=0; i < boxes.length; i++)
    boxes[i].style.opacity = "0.3";
    boxes[i].style.transform = "scaleY(10)";
    boxes[i].style.borderRadius = "0px";
    boxes[i].style.transition = "opacity 2s, transform 2s, border-radius 1s ease-in-out";
        }
    function stretchback() {
    for (var i=0; i < boxes.length; i++)
    boxes[i].style.opacity = "1";
    boxes[i].style.transform = "scaleY(1)";
    boxes[i].style.borderRadius = "10px";
    boxes[i].style.transition = "opacity 2s, transform 2s, border-radius 1s ease-in-out";               }
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you console.log(box) ?

Comment: FYI: `i < document.getElementsByClassName('skill-boxes').length;` The performance of that is bad.

Comment: At a quick glance I can see a few things wrong here actually.  For starters, you're re-declaring the same variables and overwriting their values, so your variables might not have what you think they have.  You're also iterating over a dynamically-fetched set of elements instead of over the array you're using (`box`, which should really be plural by the way).  So if anything changes the state of the DOM then those lengths might not always be equal.

Comment: @David I corrected the code and now I am only declaring the variable once as a global one. It gives the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a scoping issue. Try moving your box and skills variable declarations inside the stretch and stretchback functions.

Comment: Fair enough, second look through, seems like your for loops are missing their curly braces. Adding them in removes the error: https://codepen.io/sm1215/pen/eGbdYR

Answer (score 3):

This one is quite simple... you missed an opening curly-brace on your `for` loop:

```
 for (var i=0; i < box.length; i++) { // <-- for example, here
```

I have used `box.length` as you already have the array of elements too.

Your original code:

```
function stretch() {
for (var i=0; i < document.getElementsByClassName('skill-boxes').length; i++) // <-- OUCH
box[i].style.opacity = "0.3";
box[i].style.transform = "scaleY(10)";
```

Comment: just for a record - opening and closing braces are missing

Comment: Thanks @PiotrPasieka - and on both loops! Always use those curly braces :) https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2010/05/always-use-those-curly-braces/

Comment: You might also want to vote to close as a typographical mistake.

Answer (score 0):

How about using addEventListener('mouseenter') instead of doing hover css.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to avoid variables from overwriting, like below. Happy to elaborate if below code helps

on [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/moxeva/edit?html,js,output)

```
function stretch() { // maybe call this expand?
    var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('skill-boxes');
    var skills = document.getElementsByClassName('para');

    for (var i=0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
        boxes[i].style.opacity = "0.3";
        boxes[i].style.transform = "scaleY(10)";
        boxes[i].style.borderRadius = "0px";
        boxes[i].style.transition = "opacity 2s, transform 2s, border-radius 1s ease-in-out";
    }
}

function stretchback() { // maye call this shrink?
    var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('skill-boxes');
    var skills = document.getElementsByClassName('para');

    for (var i=0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
        boxes[i].style.opacity = "1";
        boxes[i].style.transform = "scaleY(1)";
        boxes[i].style.borderRadius = "10px";
        boxes[i].style.transition = "opacity 2s, transform 2s, border-radius 1s ease-in-out";
    }
}
```